# How can I scale down a view in Android (specifically an Ad)

Tags: android, admob

I'm working with a few different ad networks, and they all work fine and dandy on most devices, but on devices with a high screen density, they try to be helpful and scale themselves up.  But that's pretty much the opposite of what I need.

My layout is very specific to different screen sizes, and when I request ads with a specific *pixel size* from several different ad networks, they are scaled based on the screen density.  My question is this:

How can I scale the views back down to the *pixel size* I asked for?  If it helps, the ad networks I've had trouble with include JumpTap, AdMob, and, to a lesser extent, Millennial Media.

Comment: Most ad networks accept sizes in device-independent pixels, which is consistent with Android's recommendation on how to develop for all different kinds of Android devices.  These ads take up the same screen real-estate.  If they were specified as a pixel size, they would look tiny on a Galaxy Nexus and other 2.0 density devices, and that's not great for the advertiser or user (the ads don't look good and/or are unreadable, nor the ad network/publisher (users don't click on those ads).

Comment: I understand all that, really I do.  However, these ads, for some reason, are unusually large.  As in, going off the edge of the screen large.

Comment: Oooh, I have seen this once before, but I don't remember if it was just a bad creative or not.  If you rotated your device, could you see the full ad (i.e., is the image showing up as 480dp instead of 480px/320dp on a high density device?)

Comment: Well, my app is locked to landscape, so I can't really test that unfortunately